# GA4 to Big query - Dataset getting created but no tables are found

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, export

I recently connected my Google analytics (ga4) property to bigquery. I set up a daily export of the data. The data doesn't seem to get exported as I don't find any tables under the dataset in bigquery. The things I tried:

1. Delete the link and the dataset and start from scratch again. - Didn't work.
2. Check for service accounts - all were present and it still didn't work.

Issue: Dataset is getting created but the tables which should contain the raw data are not getting created.